# Polynomial Interpolation: Neville's method versus the Divided Differences method.

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I'm studying Neville's method for polynomial interpolation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville%27s_algorithm).

Is there currently any practical situation in which Neville's method is more appropriate than Newton's Divided Differences method for polynomial interpolation?

In other words, what justifies the practical use of Neville's method nowadays?

It seemed to me that Neville's method is a kind of special case of the Divided Differences method, for a single table of data.

Comment: That question is inappropriate here, since it is about the contents of a single textbook and it can only be answered by someone who has read it.

Comment: @AnotherUser: new writing